# Multiple return statement in if block

Tags: java

Why This code is not giving compile time error

```
package com.test;

public class Recursive {

    public static int name(int number) {
        if (number <= 0)
            return 0;
        return 1 + name(number / 10);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(name(124));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it?..

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not write the brackets. Each loop, `if` or `else` can be followed by a block of code (`{...}`) **or a single statement**. So your code is equivalent to:

```
package com.test;

public class Recursive {

    public static int name(int number) {
        if (number <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + name(number / 10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println(name(124));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to

```
if (n <0) {
   return 0;
}
return 1 + name (n/10);
```

This completely legal code

Comment: its `return` not `Return`

Answer (score -1):

The reason there is no compile time error is because your code is syntactically correct. If the code is not doing what you expected, please explain how.